# Why does a name error appear?

Tags: python

This is my program.

```
sentence = raw_input("Please type a sentence:" )
while "." in sentence or "," in sentence or ":" in sentence or "?" in 
sentence or ";" in sentence:
    print("Please write another sentence without punctutation ")
    sentence = input("Please write a sentence: ")
else:
    words = sentence.split()
    print(words)
specificword = raw_input("Please type a word to find in the sentence: ")
while i in range(len(words)):
    if specificword == words[i]:
        print (specificword, "found in position ", i + 1)
    else:
        print("Word not found in the sentence")
        specificword = input("Please type another word to find in the sentence")
```

After running this program this error appears,
    Please type a sentence:hello my name is jeff
    ['hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'jeff']
    Please type a word to find in the sentence: jeff

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/school/GCSE Computing/A453/Task 1/code test1.py", line 9, in <module>
    while i in range(len(words)):
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: That `while` loop is probably meant to be a `for` loop. By doing that in a while loop you are checking to see if the contents of variable `i` is contained within the list generated by the `range` function. When doing this, it is found that `i` is not defined, thus the error.

Comment: That's exactly the problem, @shadow. `for` loops define a new variable. `while` loops evaluate a condition in their scope: `i` would need to already exist. And semantically, `while i in range(len(words))` isn't what Jeff wants.

Comment: Incidentally, Jeff, look into the built-in `enumerate` function.

Answer (score 3):

```
while i in range(len(words)):
```

Needs to be `for` instead of while.

`for x in <exp>` will iterate over `<exp>` assigning the value to `x` in each iteration. In a sense it's similar to an assignment statement in that it will create the variable if it's not already defined.

`while <cond>` just evaluates the condition as an expression.

Answer (score 1):

A `NameError` is caused by using a name that isn't defined.  Either it is misspelled or has never been assigned.

In the above code, *i* hasn't been assigned yet.  The while-loop is trying to find the current value of *i* to decide whether to loop.

From the context, it looks like you intended to have a for-loop.  The difference is that the for-loop assigns the variable for you.

So replace this:

```
while i in range(len(words)):
```

With this:

```
for i in range(len(words)):
```